# React native expo icons not showing and error message

Tags: reactjs, icons, native, invisible

i have a new expo project and wanted to add some icons.

```
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

<MaterialCommunityIcons name="plus-box" size={22} />

package.json
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
        "expo": "~48.0.6",
        "react": "18.2.0",
```

The icons are not showing up (invisible) and i get this error message

```
possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Directory for 'file:///Users/home/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7DACCA8B-F88B-4249-B11F-32A19D9CE235/data/Containers/Data/Application/34AF5A49-BEA8-4B67-BE98-C6FA1CFE705C/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Faut-56300b06-9003-4b04-ae15-c87d255bd288/ExponentAsset-b62641afc9ab487008e996a5c5865e56.ttf' doesn't exist. Please make sure directory '/Users/home/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7DACCA8B-F88B-4249-B11F-32A19D9CE235/data/Containers/Data/Application/34AF5A49-BEA8-4B67-BE98-C6FA1CFE705C/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%40anonymous%2Faut-56300b06-9003-4b04-ae15-c87d255bd288' exists before calling downloadAsync.
Error: Directory for 'file:///Users/home/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7DACCA8B-F88B-4249-B11F-32A19D9CE235/data/Containers/Data/Application/34AF5A49-BEA8-4B67-BE98-C6FA1CFE705C/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Faut-56300b06-9003-4b04-ae15-c87d255bd288/ExponentAsset-b62641afc9ab487008e996a5c5865e56.ttf' doesn't exist. Please make sure directory '/Users/home/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7DACCA8B-F88B-4249-B11F-32A19D9CE235/data/Containers/Data/Application/34AF5A49-BEA8-4B67-BE98-C6FA1CFE705C/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%40anonymous%2Faut-56300b06-9003-4b04-ae15-c87d255bd288' exists before calling downloadAsync.
    at construct (native)
    at apply (native)
    at _construct (http://192.168.178.21:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:3348:28)
    at Wrapper (http://192.168.178.21:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:3310:25)
    at construct (native)
    at _createSuperInternal (http://192.168.178.21:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:96945:322)
    at call (native)
    at CodedError (http://192.168.178.21:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:96953:26)
```